# Symfony new \DateTime() always returns 00:00:00.000000

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine

Im trying to set a start and end time for a session entity.

This is how I set the starttime:

```
    public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $session = new Session();
    $session->setUserId($user);

    $date = new \DateTime();

    $date->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));

    $session->setStartTime($date);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($session);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('beverage_index', array('session' => $session->getId()));

}
```

this is how I set my endtime

```
    public function stopDrinking(Session $session)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $session->setEndTime(new \DateTime());

    $em->persist($session);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->render('drank/stop.html.twig', array(
        'session' => $session,
    ));
}
```

However when I dump my session entity it returns:

[image]

For some reason the startdate time is set to 00:00:00.000000 and not the current time. However the enddate time is set to the current time. I'm not doing anything different and still I can't get the correct startdate time.

The Session entity (startTime & endTime)

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="StartTime", type="date", nullable=true )
 */
private $startTime;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="EndTime", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $endTime;

 /**
 * Set startTime
 *
 * @param \DateTime $startTime
 *
 * @return Session
 */
public function setStartTime($startTime)
{
    $this->startTime = $startTime;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get startTime
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getStartTime()
{
    return $this->startTime;
}

/**
 * Set endTime
 *
 * @param \DateTime $endTime
 *
 * @return Session
 */
public function setEndTime($endTime)
{
    $this->endTime = $endTime;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get endTime
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getEndTime()
{
    return $this->endTime;
}
```

}

Comment: Why the timezone is Europe/Berlin if you set it to Europe/Amsterdam?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with Symphony, but what does `setStartTime()` do? And check that `$date` holds the correct information prior to adding it to the session.

Comment: setStartTime sets the startTime table in my database. I've var_dumped the $date variable and it didsplays the correct date and time. That's why it's so weird that when I persist it into the database the time is set to 0.

As you can see $date->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam')); doesn't work, for now that doesn't matter I just want the correct time in my database.

Comment: [**Sure it works**](https://3v4l.org/Ap1Vi), but I think it might be something with the `setStartTime()` method, can you share the code for that? Because if the `$date` variable is as it should be, the issue is how that variable is used, not the value it has in itself. You can also just set the timezone directly in the `DateTime` construct, [live demo](https://3v4l.org/MH2RL)

Comment: How is your `$session->startTime` is configured for `ORM`. I doubt it is `Date` instead of `DateTime`.

Comment: I've added the session entity to the question. As you can see I configured it as a DateTime object. 

It could be that I'm using the variable wrong but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've used the same code as endTime and that variable is working just fine.

Comment: does it change if you dont set the timezone? obviously you dont do this at endTime  alternative try `new \DateTime("now")`

Comment: No that doesn't work either. I've tried to use \DateTime("now") too but that doesn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you ORM definitions are wrong

use `type="datetime"` type instead of `type="date"`

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="StartTime", type="datetime", nullable=true )
 */
private $startTime;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="EndTime", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $endTime;
```

Comment: This fixed it for me!

Still it's weird that EndTime was working just fine with type="date".